# How do I make a RecyclerView horizontal scroll to have page boundaries similar to ViewPager

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am having trouble with this. I've been trying to use RecyclerView to have a page boundaries like ViewPager but prove to be difficult to do. Is there a way to overcome this problem?